# Dates not overlapping validation in teradata sql

Tags: sql, teradata

I have two columns `eff_date` and `end_date`, for which I have two input variables in SQL `in_eff_dt` and `in_end_dt`. I need to check their ranges don't overlap. For `r1` the `eff_dt` and `end_dt` are `10/02/2022` and `23/02/2022` and for `r2` it is `14/02/2022` and `01/03/2022` so their range is overlapping. I need to validate this while inputting the value in the table Main_table in UPSERT procedure.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap

Comment: Teradata supports Standard SQL `OVERLAPS` operator